# Is my drop-shadow filter syntax incorrect?

Tags: css, google-chrome

The drop-shadow filter is being ignored.

I'm a beginner, so maybe my syntax is off? The grayscale is being applied properly, so I know I'm addressing the image correctly.

```
img#mportrait{
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9));
  filter: drop-shadow(15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9));
  filter: grayscale(0.7);
}
```

The result in page inspection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49u8D.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Each successive filter rule overrules the last. So what you want to do is combine the rules with whitespace between, repeating `grayscale()` in both the prefixed and non-prefixed version of the rule:

```
img#mportrait{
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9)) grayscale(0.7);
  filter: drop-shadow(15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9)) grayscale(0.7);
}
```

The `grayscale()` only works in your example because it's the only rule being applied, after canceling out the preceding rules.

Comment: Success! Thank you so much c:

Answer (score -2):

The drop-shadow is its own property, which is `box-shadow: ____`.
So your code would be:

```
img#mportrait{
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9));
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
  filter: grayscale(0.7);
}
```

This is from [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and [this W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_shadows.asp).
Hope it helps.

Comment: You should probably provide a reference that says it is its own property, as [at least one well-respected documentation source says otherwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added 2 links, both to well-respected documentation sources.

Comment: You also edited your answer to use `box-shadow` instead of `drop-shadow` which is what the question is about. We can see the edit history.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know, I wrote the property wrong at first. And also, `box-shadow` does the same thing as `drop-shadow`, but has more support according to this CanIUse for `drop-shadow`: https://caniuse.com/#search=drop-shadow and this CanIUse for `box-shadow`: https://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow.